# how to run a PostgreSQL query on CartoDB tables?

Tags: postgresql, sql, carto

I want to run a [VACUUM FULL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VACUUM_FULL) on my table, but I don't think it's working.

Simply `sandorl.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=VACUUM&api_key={MYKEY}` results in long output, apparently only repeating for various items that `only superuser or database owner can vacuum it.` I am the owner, of course.

If I try to specify the table (`sandorl.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=VACUUM%20FULL&table=location_of_winners25mb&api_key={MYKEY}`), I get `{"time":0.047,"fields":{},"total_rows":null,"rows":[]}`

What is there to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the API. If you want to be sure you run your query, just work from the table view. From some CartoDB documentation (without a direct link for some reason):

> SQL in CartoDB
>
> To perform an SQL query in CartoDB, first load the
>   table from your Dashboard. Once you have opened your table, in the
>   lower right corner of your table you will see a button SQL, click it.
>   This brings up a small text input window, from here you can enter any
>   SQL query for your table and run it.
>   [image]